# How to display the position of other users on maps - Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to develop an android application, set apart from other features, I'm stuck on the **Google Maps API **. 
Let me explain, I would like to display on a map the **position of several users** in a application on Android examle by myself and show its location **with a marker.**

So I turn to you for **infomations** and integration can be a **code for it!**

Sorry for my english, I'm **french**!

Thank you in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question at all. But from the topic I can assure that you are willing to display the locations of different users in map in a device. For this every other user most be online and he/she should **send their location to some place(like database)** and you need to read the location details from database and display it on map.

Edited:
Try to use service in users' system, and read it from database. For this you need to try first using online database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's exactly it, but do you have a code or procedure to do this?

Comment: You need to ask specific question. eg: How to insert to online database using android? How to delete? How to count and display in textView